# why are "float-start" and "float-end" disconnecting my <span> elements from the div?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-float

I'm running reactjs and attempting to use `float-start` and `float-end` to position "start" and "end" `span` elements on the left and right side of a `div`, respectively.

I've boiled it down to this basic demo:

`index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <div className="my-red-container">
      <span>things</span>
    </div>

    <div className="my-yellow-container">
      <span className='float-start'>left</span>
      <span className='float-end'>right</span>
    </div>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

`index.css`:

```
.my-yellow-container {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.my-red-container {
  background-color: red;
}
```

When I use `npm start` to run this, I expect to see a red bar saying "things" followed by a yellow bar saying "left" on the left and "right" on the right. Instead I get this:

[image]

If I move the red div below the yellow div like this:

```
    <div className="my-yellow-container">
      <span className='float-start'>left</span>
      <span className='float-end'>right</span>
    </div>

    <div className="my-red-container">
      <span>things</span>
    </div>
```

Then I expect to get a yellow bar saying "left" on the left and "right" on the right, and below that a red bar saying "things". Instead I get this:

[image]

But when I add an "unclassed" `span` to the yellow div, like this:

```
    <div className="my-yellow-container">
      <span>far left</span>
      <span className='float-start'>left</span>
      <span className='float-end'>right</span>
    </div>

    <div className="my-red-container">
      <span>things</span>
    </div>
```

Then I get this instead:

[image]

It's like the `float-start` and `float-end` completely disconnect the `span` from it's containing `div` and then all the text gets jumbled.

Please help. What did I mess up? I've clearly overlooked something, but I don't know what.

Comment: this is 100% CSS-related question. Nobody knows what `float-start` and `float-end` styles are(well, there is a chance it comes from some known library and someone guesses looking onto classname, but chances are rather low)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered from a previous answer (that was somehow deleted before I could tag it as the answer) that I had to set the containing `div` to this:

```
<div style={{ overflow: "hidden" }}>
...
</div>
```

This seemed to do the trick. The (now-deleted) post explained that "float" intentionally disconnects the floating child from the dimension restrictions of the parent, but setting the style `overflow: "hidden"` forces them back into containment again. I just wanted the "far left" and "far right" feature of `float-start` and `float-end`, so I'm fine forcing it the child element back into containment again.